# PHP array with fixed values

Tags: php, arrays, static, global-variables

can anybody tell me with example? is there a way to permanently(or till we restart the server) store variables in PHP array.

I have heard of static array & global variables kind of things, but I can't get them together.

```
$storearray = array();
array_push($storearray, "apple", "ball"); 
//in 30mins
array_push($storearray, "land", "band");
//in 1 hour
array_push($storearray, "bland", "aband");
```

when I chk the array I want all the elements to be there

Comment: If you want to store data permanent, you have to save it into a db or a file.

Comment: persistent storage is done through a database, not a global variable.

Comment: "when i chk the array i want all the elements to be there" : there is something called databases for that, you store data into them and retrieve it whenever needed

Comment: Guys database calls are expensive operations... this is just to save data... just a llike saving a cookie in a session..

Answer (score 0):

Use a DATABASE:

example: `MYSQL`

Comment: @vivoconunxino: Yeah that too :D

Comment: well.. if he restarts I think memcache might loss the data, but not sure

Comment: Guys database calls are expensive operations... this is just to save data... just a llike saving a cookie in a session...